# Model shows in Text in .CSHTML view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a cshtml view and in there I have used Model. But the problem is that model shows in my View.

```
@Model LMM.NEWS.Documents;


@{
    Layout = null;
    ViewBag.Title = "News Doc Download";
}
```

In my view, It shows me in the text like below. How to solve this?

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[LMM.Entities.DTO.NEWS.Documents] LMM.Entities.DTO.NEWS.Documents;
```

Here i have attached,my model shows in text in my view
[image]

Comment: `@model LMM.NEWS.Documents` with lower case

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov then it shows me 'Document is a type' which i not valid in the given context

Comment: `@Model` directive will show current model's fully-qualified type instead of defining a viewmodel.

Comment: Can you post your view please?

Comment: `@model List<LMM.NEWS.Documents>`

Answer (score 0):

Is because of this line:

```
@Model LMM.NEWS.Documents;
```

it's calling the toString(); method from Object, one solution is to override toString(); on your **Documents** class:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Empty;
}
```

Not completely sure if that fixes your problem because I don't have a project to test it out, but you could try.